# Get the index of median value in array containing Nans

Tags: python, numpy, nan, median

How can I get the index of the median value for an array which contains NaNs?

For example, I have the array of values `[Nan, 2, 5, NaN, 4, NaN, 3, 1]` with correspondent array of errors on those values `[np.nan, 0.1, 0.2, np.nan, 0.1, np.nan, 0.4, 0.3]`. Then the median is `3`, while the error is `0.4`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

EDIT: I edited the error array to imply a more realistic situation. And Yes, I am using numpy.

Comment: What do you want if there are multiple values at the median, as in `[1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: @DSM, you mean the median itself or the error? The median is defined for an array of even values as well.

Comment: @Py-ser: in your title and in your question you refer to the **index** of the median value, not the median value.

Comment: @DSM, you are right. However, I explained a clear example about the practical use of the index. I thought the index was the best way to get the index of the error array. Anyway, in the case you mention, I suppose two indices are necessary.

Comment: This isn't nearly as clearly defined a problem as you seem to think it is.  In the case of `[1,2,3,4]`, the median -- 2.5 -- isn't an element of the array.  What indices do you want returned?  What about `[2,2,2,3,3,3]`?  Do you want every index returned?  Etc.

Comment: You want the index of the median in case of odd numbers and the indices of the two values from which you get the median, in the case of even numbers. In the last case, the two returned indices would be `[2, 3]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70320/discussion-between-dsm-and-py-ser).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really clear how you intend to meaningfully extract the error from the median, but if you do happen to have an array such that the median is one of its entries, and the corresponding error array is defined at the corresponding index, and there aren't other entries with the same value as the median, and probably several other disclaimers, then you can do the following:

```
a = np.array([np.nan,2,5,np.nan, 4,np.nan,3,1])
aerr = np.array([np.nan, 0.1, 0.2, np.nan, 0.1, np.nan, 0.4, 0.3])

# median, ignoring NaNs
amedian = np.median(a[np.isfinite(a)])
# find the index of the closest value to the median in a
idx = np.nanargmin(np.abs(a-amedian))
# this is the corresponding "error"
aerr[idx]
```

EDIT: as @DSM points out, if you have NumPy 1.9 or above, you can simplify the calculation of `amedian` as `amedian = np.nanmedian(a)`.

Comment: If we know this is what the OP is after, we can use `np.nanmedian` in modern `numpy` to simply the `amedian` line a little.

Answer (score 2):

numpy has everything you need:

```
values = np.array([np.nan, 2, 5, np.nan, 4, np.nan, 3, 1])
errors = np.array([np.nan, 0.1, 0.2, np.nan, 0.1, np.nan, 0.4, 0.3])

# filter
filtered = values[~np.isnan(values)]
# find median
median = np.median(filtered)
# find indexes
indexes = np.where(values == median)[0]
# find errors
errors[indexes] # array([ 0.4])
```

Answer (score 0):

let say you have your list named as "a", then you can use this codeto find a masked array without "Nan" and then do median with a `np.ma.median()`:

```
a=[Nan, 2, 5, NaN, 4, NaN, 3, 1]
am = numpy.ma.masked_array(a, [numpy.isnan(x) for x in a])
numpy.ma.median(am)
```

you can do the same for errors as well.

Comment: I am not sure this is doing what I need.

Comment: This will ignore your Nan values